# Precision issue with sscanf

Tags: c++, floating-point, scanf

I am reading some values from text file using sscanf and store them to double using %lf.

but values are becoming rounded off. for example

what is read : 5.655035220-E02
what is stored: 0.0565504

I think it has something to do with format specifier "%lf".

Please suggest proper format specifier for reading and storing values , as it is.

Comment: How do you print the stored value or do you look at it with breakpoints? If you print it it might be the printout that prints with less percision.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @devnull You mean the document that says that double-precision IEEE 754 numbers carry about 16 decimal digits of precision? How does that explain seeing `0.0565504`? (the explanation is simple, but I do not think it is found in the document you cite so automatically)

Comment: @Flipbed i tried both . both are showing truncated values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems

Your `printf()` specifier is rounding off too many bits
(Maybe) Your floating point variable is unable to retain all the desired precision.

suggested format specifier:
reading: `sscanf(buffer, "%le", &d)`
storing: `printf("%.*le", DECIMAL_DIG /* or DBL_DIG+3 */, d)`

---

Problem 1

```
double d;
sscanf("5.655035220e-02", "%lf", &d);
printf("%.7lf\n", d);  // 0.0565504
printf("%.7le\n", d);  // 5.6550352e-02
printf("%.9le\n", d);  // 5.655035220e-02
```

Had you printed out using the `%e`, their would be more significant numbers rather the `%f` with its leading zero digits.  The number you see is a rounded value.  It is *not* the number stored which was 5.65503522000000008...e-02

---

Problem 2

Had you used the the type `float`, rather than `double`, you may have experienced loss of precision as `5.655035220e-02` is `5.65503537...e-02` in typical 4-byte floating point.

---

Recommend @devnull idea above about reading *What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 3):

You mean that you have written code like so (thanks for providing your code next time, by the way, it really helps understanding what is going on rather than having to rely on vague clues):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  double v2;
  sscanf("5.655035220e-02", "%lf", &v2);
  printf("%f\n", v2);
  return 0;
}
```

And you obtain results like:

```
0.056550
```

(Give or take a decimal digit.)

You problem is not in the decimal-to-double conversion in `sscanf()`, which is fine, but in the double-to-decimal conversion of `printf()`. Variable `v2` contains a good approximation of the number you scanned. You are simply not requesting `printf()` to print many digits of this approximation. Try:

```
printf("%.10f\n", v2);
0.0565503522
```

Comment: thanks for your response. you see, i am not printing out the values , rather using them in some calculation, which is yielding wrong result. If i check the contents of variables in debug mode , it is showing me rounded off values. If i explicitly   mention all the values for calculation (eg: double tt=  5.655035220e-02; ) , it yields expected results.

Comment: @rwik It is impossible to do more to answer your question until you have clarified what you mean by “what is read” and “what is stored”. I still think you are confusing “what is stored” with “what gets printed”, whichever way you obtain it. We need whatever your actual code is.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this code,

```
double tt=  5.655035220e-02;
printf("%le",tt);
getchar();
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the same as IAM HERE's post. The problem is that you wrote the value as 5.6...20-e02 but it should be 5.6...20e-02 (NOTE, - after the E, not before!).

Comment: I think this is just a typo in the question not present in the code that the OP is resolute about not showing us. Scanning `"5.655035220-E02"` yields `5.6550…`, not `0.056550…`.

Comment: Ah true. Well then OP must have a fault in the code or an incorrect implementation in the compiler/os that he is using.

Comment: I think the OP is confused and is not providing us the means to help him. `0.0565504` is one correctly-rounded decimal representation of the closest `double` to `5.655035220E-02`. There is no reason to think that `scanf()` has done anything wrong.